# What is the default login password for the telnetd server?

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to access the telnetd server on my D-Link Wireless AC1200 dual band gigabit range extender (DAP-1650) but I do not have the login password. I have attempted common passwords such as "admin", "password", and leaving it blank, but none have been successful.

Comment: Try user1 / test and blank / blank